# Saving the index in Whoosh

Tags: python, python-2.7, whoosh

I was looking a suggestion or preferably an example, to store or save the index of Whoosh. I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 Professional. 
If anyone may kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Whoosh is well documented , you can find most of things in the [Official documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/index.html). Here is the example of the Indexer-Searcher from the Quick Start:

```
# Indexer
>>> from whoosh.index import create_in
>>> from whoosh.fields import *
>>> schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT)
>>> ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
>>> writer = ix.writer()
>>> writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path=u"/a",
...                     content=u"This is the first document we've added!")
>>> writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", path=u"/b",
...                     content=u"The second one is even more interesting!")
>>> writer.commit()

# Searcher 
>>> from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
>>> with ix.searcher() as searcher:
...     query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse("first")
...     results = searcher.search(query)
...     results[0]
...
{"title": u"First document", "path": u"/a"}
```

The example is explained in details [there](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/quickstart.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to store the index and retrieve the index later to search. I used a slightly different method from whoosh.filedb.filestore import FileStorage if not os.path.exists("C:\Python27\IndexFiles\indexnew1"):
 os.mkdir("C:\Python27\IndexFiles\indexnew1") >>> storage3 = FileStorage("C:\Python27\IndexFiles\indexnew1")
>>> ix = storage3.create_index(schema)
>>> writer = ix.writer()   seems going fine.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for a nice discussion and your kind time.

Comment: @Searcher just a reminder for marking answer as accepted https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Do I have to click anywhere? Where is that? Please suggest. I do not know. Regards.

Comment: @Searcher Click on the good mark sign of my answer like in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png . It will be green after clicking